# Авторизация с Selenium WebDriver через cookie

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, auth

Необходимо реализовать авторизацию с Selenium WebDriver так что-бы не вводить логин и пароль для сайтов каждый раз при запуске. Тоесть нужно сэмитировать хранение логинов в менеджере паролей и куках.

Как результат должно получиться, что при открытии сайта получалось что вход уже выполнен, как это бывает при открытии обычного браузера на сайтах где уже авторизировался и сохранил пару логин/пароль.

Возможно ли это, и если да, то как? Спасибо.

Пробовал так, но не работает:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.ru/");
driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("Username", "myLoginValue", "www.google.ru", "/", null));
driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("Password", "myPasswordValue", "www.google.ru", "/", null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас не работает, потому что вы передаете дату как `null`.
Попробуйте сделать так - один раз зайдите, заберите все куки, сохраните их в файл (например) и потом доставайте оттуда. Т.е. будет примерно так

первый запуск

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//login
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
saveToFile(new File("/path/to/file), cookies);
driver.quit();
```

И потом просто парсите файл и собирайте куки.